# EaselJS example code fixes

Tags: easeljs

Anyone had trouble running the code samples provided with EaselJS 1.0.0? I tried running HelloWorld, it failed; but I found if I made the following two changes it seemed to work:

1) Body Onload

```
<body onload=init();> <!-- WORKS -->
<body onload="init();"> <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
```

2) Script tag

```
<script src="easeljs-NEXT.js"></script>  <!-- WORKS -->
<script src="../lib/easeljs.combined.js"></script> <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
```

Fix #2 deserves a small explanation -- using search in Finder I find no file named easeljs.combined.js.

Maybe this will help the next person who dives into EaselJS sample code. Feel free to let me know if I'm missing something.

Required to wrap HTML in comments like this above? Preview suggested so.

Comment: Looks like preview failed! How do I add code to a question?

Comment: Fixed your preview.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspicious that your first example doesn't work as shown. Do you have an example handy?

As for the second one, where are those scripts coming from? You would have had to manually include either/or. If you copied example code from [GitHub](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/), the `lib/` folder lives outside the `examples/` folder, so it has to be relatively referenced a directory up.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the preview issue.

Comment: I'm not going to debate the issue. The code comes from the Hello World example that ships with EaselJS version 1.0.0. My version did not come from GitHub, rather a zip file downloaded from the EaselJS site. If that sample works for everyone else, wonderful. Failed for me. I investigated, and made the changes as outlined above to make the example work.

Comment: Yep, not looking to debate it, just saying that the quotes are the correct way to do it, and removing them should certainly not fix it. I suspect something else is going on. To test, I downloaded this file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/master/examples/HelloWorld.html), modified the Easel source to point at the CDN, and it ran fine in Chrome. Do you have a zip with the non-working `onload` usage? Is there a certain browser its not working in? Are you running it locally or on a server?

Comment: Sorry for the crusty response. Yes, I have a zip with the non-working onload usage. Are you hinting there's some way to pass the zip to you? I will if I can. I was running the code locally on a MacBook (OS X 10.11.5) on Chromium 68.0.3406.0 - assuming the build today is the same as I used yesterday. Hmm...I'll try it on a couple other browsers and see if I can run it non-locally as well.

Comment: Just fixing the filename is enough to make the sample run. Apparently my 2nd "fix" to the onload parameter was not needed. IF THE FILENAME IS NOT FIXED the sample will fail on my MacBook in 4 different browsers: Chromium 68.0.3406.0, Chrome 67.0.3396.87, Firefox 60.0.2, and Safari 9.1.1.